# Using python argparse module for arguments starting with hyphen

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7. I am writing a script that uses argparse module for parsing command line arguments. The issue is there is an option -t, --tdiff that takes in time difference specified as +/-HH:MM:SS.

I coded the same as following, say in file myprog.py:

```
parser.add_argument("-t", "--tdiff",
                    action="store",
                    dest="time_diff",
                    help = "Specify time difference as +/-HH:MM:SS.")
```

Now I can run the program like "./myprog.py -t +02:30:00" but not as "./myprog.py -t -02:30:00".

Running the prog with time difference with leading hyphen prints the usage. Please help how can I circumvent this.

Comment: You can use a different prefix . . . https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dislike changing the option prefix to something non-standard. Here are two approaches that I've used to handle option values that begin with a hyphen.

```
# Use a different symbol for negative times.
--tdiff ~02:30:00

# Use this syntax on the command line.
--tdiff=-02:30:00
```

Comment: +1 for the `--tdiff=-XX:XX:XX` option.  That's what I would do too (I'm not a fan of changing the prefix-chars either).

Comment: Yup I checked. And it works without meddling with prefix_chars. Following usage works: `-t=-02:30:00` or `-t="-02:30:00"` or `-t-02:30:00`.
Following doesn't work: `-t -02:30:00` or `-t "-02:30:00"`.

Comment: I will accept this answer as this is closes to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

That - prefix is being parsed as an option, you can try to workaround this by changing the prefix used for options with [`prefix_chars`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) Check out the example they give in the linked page.

Comment: You are totally right, quotes won't fix it. Did some search in the docs and found a correct workaround by using prefix_chars.